# Magento Product Video Autoplay base not working for Vimeo Video

Tags: magento2, product-video

**Magento Product Video Autoplay** base not working for Vimeo Video.

The video is not loading when video icon is clicked.

**Is there any other way to make the video auto play ?**

Answer (score 0):

To Autoplay vimeo Video you need to add this on URL.

[image]

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Where are you suggesting to add this?  If the video is added in "Images And Videos" on the product edit form in the admin, where would this be updated?  It seems like you are thinking this is added in the description or something

Comment: No you need to put this in URL.

Comment: Sorry, this still does not make sense, if I try and add embed code into the URL is does not work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIfgK.png as image shows I get: Attention
Error: "Invalid video url" - where is the URL field you are talking about?

Comment: I think you need to write in Url = https://vimeo.com/linkofvideo?autoplay=1

Comment: Checked, I just do not see this "Embed" field and changing the Url to add query params (instead of added embed code) has no effect of starting video automatically on product page